# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input Discord.js v12+

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

I honestly cant see why this is happening to me, Its so confusing at this point. Any helpful tips?

Here is the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
> at JSON.parse ()
> at Client. (/home/container/index.js:728:31)
> at Client.emit (node:events:406:35)
> at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
> at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
> at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
> at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
> at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
> at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)

here is the code:

```
    let stickies = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./stickyones.json", "utf8"));
bot.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (message.author.id == bot.user.id) return;
    if(!message.guild) return
    let stickies = await JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("stickyones.json", "utf8"));

    if(stickies[message.channel.id]) {
        let lastMessage = await message.channel.messages.fetch(stickies[message.channel.id].lastId);
        lastMessage.delete();
        let newMessage = await message.channel.send(`:warning: __***Sticky Message, Read Before Typing!***__ :warning:\n${stickies[message.channel.id].message}`);

        stickies[message.channel.id] = {
            lastId: newMessage.id,
            message: stickies[message.channel.id].message
        };
        fs.writeFile("stickyones.json", JSON.stringify(stickies), (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
        });
    }
});
```

This is the line that it says is wrong :

```
let stickies = await JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("stickyones.json", "utf8"));
```

Im using `graceful-fs` for the `fs.readFileSync`

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("graceful-fs");
const ms = require("ms");
let stickies = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./stickyones.json", "utf8"));

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let stickies = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./stickyones.json", "utf8"));
    message.delete();
    if(message.member.roles.cache.some(r=>["834130492219588671", "858710670299627551"].includes(r.id)) ) {
    } else {
      return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, No.`)
    }

    if(stickies[message.channel.id]) { // Already a sticky
        delete stickies[message.channel.id];
        fs.writeFile("./stickyones.json", JSON.stringify(stickies), (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
        });
        return message.channel.send("Sticky message removed.").then(msg => {
           msg.delete({ timeout: 10000 })
       })
        .catch(console.error);
    } else { // No sticky yet
        return message.channel.send("There's no sticky set in this channel.").then(msg => {
           msg.delete({ timeout: 10000 })
       })
        .catch(console.error);
    }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "removesticky"
}
```

This is my removesticky command^

Comment: Can you show `stickyones.json`? Is it a valid JSON file?

Comment: @dan1st it is a valid file but thats where the message gets stored to do anything with it. Once I use ".removesticky" Which is the command to remove the sticky message it instantly deletes the `{}` that are in that file along with the sticky...I can give a quick example

```stickyones.json```

`{"834130493477355629":{"lastId":"880505707726790677","message":"test"}}`

if I were to remove the sticky message via the command the file would completely end up being blank and it would crash my bot.


```stickyones.json```

[empty]

Comment: It means you are missing `}`s, or the file is empty.

Comment: What is `.removesticky`?

Comment: @MrMythical Yeah I understand that but when I run my delete command the brackets are not supposed to be deleting whatsoever.  Check the edited version of the post for the delete command

Comment: How big is your JSON file currently? Also, how often does this issue happen? Does it always happen, or only after some time?

Comment: @theusaf here is everything in the file 

```{"875007440918306856":{"lastId":"880506908560207943","message":"Please type `!d bump` to bump the server in the disboard list. type `/status` to get the server info!"},"834130493477355629":{"lastId":"880554286352859239","message":"welcome to RCRP read the rules"}}```

and everytime I run the command